# display total in field on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have a function that I would like to display the total in a div and it's not working. Any ideas?

Basically, on blur take the input value in the vehiclePrice and multiply it by 10% (0.010) and then display that total as a two decimal fixed amount in the estimatedTaxesAndFees field.

HTML:

```
<label for="vehiclePrice" class="form-control-label vpl">Vehicle Price</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="vehiclePrice" placeholder="$0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onBlur="addCommas(this)" value="28435" />
<label for="estimatedTaxesAndFees" class="form-control-label etfl">Estimated Taxes and Fees</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="estimatedTaxesAndFees" placeholder="$0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onBlur="addCommas(this)"/>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("body").on("blur", "#vehiclePrice", function () {
            updateTotalNetVehicle();
        });
        var updateTotalNetVehicle = function () {
            var input1 = parseInt($('#vehiclePrice').val()) || 0;
            var number1 = 0.10;
            var sum = input1 * number1;
            $('#estimatedTaxesAndFees').text('$' + sum.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'));
        };
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/icweat/4aufj/3/)

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: addCommas is not defined`

Comment: That was for something else...My bad. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/icweat/4aufj/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. New [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WVbB8/)

1. Removed onBlur='addComas' from the html.
2. Moved the function declaration outside of the document.ready scope.
3. Changed $('#estimatedTaxesAndFees').text to $('#estimatedTaxesAndFees').val
4. Changed listen event to

$("#vehiclePrice").on("blur", function () {
                updateTotalNetVehicle();
});

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $("#vehiclePrice").on("blur", function () {
                updateTotalNetVehicle();
            });

        });
    });

     var updateTotalNetVehicle = function () {
                var input1 = parseInt($('#vehiclePrice').val()) || 0;
                var number1 = 0.10;
                var sum = input1 * number1;
                $('#estimatedTaxesAndFees').val('$' + sum.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'));
            };
```

Comment: Working as I need it thank you. Have 4 mins before I can accept the answer.

Comment: @isaacweathers Glad I could help! Please mark correct answer if it resolved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

`#estimatedTaxesAndFees` is an input element so `.text()` will not work

Use `.val()` instead.

```
$('#estimatedTaxesAndFees')
    .val($('#estimatedTaxesAndFees').text('$' + sum.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'));
```

---

in the jsfiddle you also have some methods called from inline attributes that do not exist in the code.